# Difference between vmapping a vmapped function versus the output of a vmapped function

Tags: python, jax

I am going through a great set of JAX notebooks that contain exercises on [Eric Ma's GitHub](https://github.com/ericmjl/dl-workshop/tree/master/notebooks/02-jax-idioms).

The task that I am interested in is to replicate the following function via multiple `vmap` function applications:

```
data = random.normal(key, shape=(11, 31, 7))

def ex2_numpy_equivalent(data):
    result = []
    for d in data: 
        cp = jnp.cumprod(d, axis=-1)
        s = jnp.sum(cp, axis=1)
        result.append(s)
    return jnp.stack(result)
```

The solution provided by Eric was:

```
def loopless_loop_ex2(data):
    """Data is three-dimensional of shape (n_datasets, n_rows, n_columns)"""

    def inner(dataset):
        """dataset is two-dimensional of shape (n_rows, n_columns)"""
        cp = vmap(np.cumpred)(dataset)
        s = vmap(np.sum)(cp)
        return s 

    return vmap(inner)(data)
```

My initial "guess solution" was to try:

```
func1 = vmap(jnp.cumprod)
func2 = vmap(jnp.sum)
func3 = vmap(func2)

func3(data)
```

Alarm bells were ringing because it makes no sense for `func3` to be a `vmap'ped version of` func2`, considering that` func2`is already a`vmap'ped function. While I did get the incorrect answer (value-wise), the dimensions of the answer matched the expected sizes. What is this getting up to?

After looking at Eric's solution, it seems pretty apparent that you can/should only be *chaining* `vmap` functions after you pass or evaluate the nested `vmap` function, but when you *don't* do this, and instead use my incorrect first attempt, what is going on?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason your computation is different is that you never compute the `cumprod` of the input. You create a function `func1 = vmap(jnp.cumprod)`, but never call that function. Rather you're effectively computing `vmap(vmap(jnp.sum))(data)`, which for 3-dimensional input is equivalent to the sum along the last axis:

```py
import jax.numpy as jnp
from jax import random, vmap

key = random.PRNGKey(1234)
data = random.normal(key, shape=(11, 31, 7))

# func1 = vmap(jnp.cumprod) # unused
func2 = vmap(jnp.sum)
func3 = vmap(func2)

assert jnp.allclose(func3(data), data.sum(-1))
```